# How to correct the issue in loading HTML page content in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pageload

I'm working on an HTML website. I'm adding a header and footer content from HTML files to each HTML file in my website using jQuery. The issue I'm facing is at the time of loading of a page. While loading the page, the content first moves to top-left corner of a screen then after loading the whole page content the page looks proper. I'm not under standing why this is happening and what's the issue? For your reference following is the link of one of my webpages of my website:
[This is a link from my website for your reference](http://eprimehtml.eywaharvest.com/eywaz.com/Gangamai_hospital_22_05/html/why-choose-us-location.html)
Can some one please help me in correcting the issue and loading the page? If you want any more further details I can provide you the same.

Comment: why exactly are you using jQuery to import the files? Have you considered php?

Comment: @TerisL: I can't use any server side language. I want a pure HTML website and I want to achieve using client side scripts only.

Comment: I see, my guess is that it has something to do with importing at least the header-css part. Since its loading it like a step at a time you can see the "progress" of the loading and not just the final result.

Comment: Easiest way to fix this is to hide the content while it is being loaded and then display it when the loading is done. Maybe showing a spinner or something similar while loading is in progress.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: What will happen when visitor deactivated javascript on browser?

Comment: Hiding is probably the best you can do, BUT: since you load the entire content via JS, consider turning your page into a single page application that works without reloading the page, ever.

Comment: if you have any `css links` in your `header.html,footer.html` , put that links whithin your `main document` , that might fix the issue

Comment: PLease some body provie me the precise and workable answer.

Comment: +1 for @Xantier in my opinion.

Comment: The problem is with your `css` and the way you append the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are loading header and footer before the html document (DOM) is ready. You must use document.ready function as below in your script tag. I hope this will solve your problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#container_header").load("header.html"); 
      $("#container_footer").load("footer.html"); 
});

</script>
```